# Average value of power spectral density

Tags: matlab, power-spectral-density

I have a spectra of power spectral density (PSD) (`vector (1:1e6)`) from experimental data (blue color).

[image]

However I want to plot only average value of PSD (red curve).

How can I do it by using MATLAB?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Just my usual ranting: the PSD **is** a stochastic expectation value. What you have, based on an experiment, is an *estimate* of the PSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove low frequency content of the diagram. Simply use [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) filter. find the optimum filter size that produces your desired result. Here is a matlab example code.

```
t=0:0.001:1;
PSD=2*sin(2*pi*1*t)+10*randn(size(t))+5; %assume as the power spectrum
filtered=zeros(size(t));
M=20 ;% Moving average filter size
for i=1:length(t)-M
    filtered(i)=mean(PSD(i:i+M));
end
plot(PSD);
hold on
plot(filtered,'r')
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I need to plot the frequency dispersion of frequency noise from laser. That why I have to use the frequency in this graph.

Comment: Actually, by frequency, I do not mean the frequency of actual data (which in your case is noise from laser). I meant to consider the PSD plot itself as a signal.